# Create directory with several subfolders in PowerShell? (I know how to do it in Bash)

Tags: bash, powershell

I want to do the following in PowerShell, but it seems like the curly brackets pose an issue.

Here's how I would do it in Bash:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/dir/{dir1,dir2,dir3...dir10}
```

This creates a parent directory, then several directories of which "dir" contains several subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory C:\temp1\dir1,C:\temp1\dir2,C:\temp1\dir3
```

one more way

```
$dirs = 1..10


$dirs | % {
  New-Item -ItemType Directory ( Join-Path -Path 'c:\temp\dir' -ChildPath ('dir' +$_  ) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are after Directories 1 to 10 (or similar) - something like the following will work for you:

```
1..10 | ForEach {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ("C:\Temp\Dir" + $_)
}
```

If you are looking to create an array of named subfolders - the something like the following will work (including the ability to create sub-sub-folders:

```
$subFolderNameArray = @(
    "folder1",
    "Folder2",
    "Folder1\Subfolder3"
)
ForEach ($subFolderName in $subFolderNameArray) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ("C:\Temp\" + $subFolderName)
}
```

This relies on creating the folders in teh correct order (you must create parent folders before subfolders).  If you want to do things out of order (or can't guarantee the starting array will be tree-wise) - you can use the force switch:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ("C:\Temp\Folder\Subfolder") -Force
```